# 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found when trying to bridge for react native

Tags: swift, react-native

I am currently building a widget using widgetkit for my react native application. However, I keep getting `RCTBridgeModule.h` file not found. I created theese 3 files. Any ideas what I am missing

**RCTMyProjectModule.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyProjectWidgetModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(refreshAllWidgets)

@end
```

**RCTMyProjectModule.h**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

**MyProjectWidgetModule.swift**

```
import Foundation
import WidgetKit

@objc(MyProjectWidgetModule)
class MyProjectWidgetModule: NSObject {
  
  @objc(refreshAllWidgets)
  func refreshAllWidgets() {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error on my RCTMyProjectModule.m file. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Search for your project bridging header file inside ios folder, it's look like **ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h**

Then add the followings imports to the end

```
// Headers React Native
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>
```